# My Windows Credential Manager is not updating my Gitlab passwords

Tags: git, credentials-manager

I needed to update my passwords and after that I tried to update Windows Credential Manager for my Gitlab credential, but it doesn't want to accept my new password.

Comment: Why not just delete the old password in Credential Manager and re-log in into Gitlab?

Comment: When I delete the password and add a new credential the old password is still there. But I nuked the whole credentials manager and now I need to log in every time when pushing to Git, but at least it's working.